# How to save ajax XML Result to disk

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, xml

I feel like I am spending too much time for this.I am getting an xml document from a database with an ajax call .The result is in an XML format ,instead of displaying it, I need to have the user download it. 
Is there any way to do this that will work both in IE, FF and Chrome ?

```
function DownloadXML(XML_ID) {

$.ajax({
    url: 'webservices/DownloadXML.svc/' + XML_ID,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        //download xml here
    },
    error: onError
});
```

}

Comment: Simplest is set server to force download and simply open that url without ajax

Comment: alternative - https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: @charlietfl Can you show an example ? This is not an MVC project so I can't use any System.MVC libraries.